# Async, Lambda, Boto3, ThreadPoolExecutor: Connection pool is full, discarding connection

Tags: python, asynchronous, aws-lambda, boto3, threadpoolexecutor

**Some Context:**

I'm developing a test suite for updating and testing global redirects using CodePipeline and two lambda functions: a wrapper function and a tester function.

The wrapper loops through a list of domains.  For each domain, it grabs the associated S3 file, then creates a long list of objects (one object per line in the file).  Example object:

```
redirect = {
     'staging': None,
     'prod': None,
     'country': 'US',
     'language': 'EN',
     'status_code': None,
     'shortlink': None,
     'expected': None
}
```

The wrapper then takes this list of objects and calls the second lambda (the tester lambda) which sends a series of httpx requests for each object etc. etc.

> *The most important piece of this is that it is asynchronous - otherwise, the lambda will time out at the 15 minute mark.*

**The Actual Issue:**

The wrapper function can only trigger the tester 10 times. Otherwise, when the result is returned, I get this error:

```
Connection pool is full, discarding connection: lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

I've bumped up the max_workers for ThreadPoolExecutor and even set max_workers for boto3.  I spoke to AWS support and my actual lambda settings are conducive to my tester lambda being triggered as many times as needed. And, yet, I'm still getting the connection pool error.

**Relevant Code:**

```
from botocore.client import Config
from boto3.session import Session
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import boto3

max_pool_connections = 30

config = Config(
    max_pool_connections=max_pool_connections,
    read_timeout = 900
)

def handler(event, context):
    try:
        events = ... # generated via a bunch of nonsense 

        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_pool_connections) as executor:
            futures = []
            for event in events:
                print(event)
                future = executor.submit(lambda_client.invoke, FunctionName = "site-tester", InvocationType = "RequestResponse", Payload = json.dumps(event))
                futures.append(future)

            for index, future in enumerate(as_completed(futures, timeout=None), start=1):
                ...
```

This is (obviously) not the full code because the full code is an absolute train wreck of nonsense.  I don't have time at the moment to create a full test function but if anyone has any initial thoughts or troubleshooting tips it would be greatly appreciated.

I do want to note, that for the 10 events that do get called and return, everything is working as expected.  It's just limited to 10 times and I definitely need it to be more than that.

> *AGAIN the most important piece of this is that it is asynchronous - otherwise, the lambda will time out at the 15 minute mark.*

**Concurrency Settings**

wrapper function: reserved concurrency set to 30

tester function: reserved concurrency set to 30

Comment: I highly recommend you take a look at AWS [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/). They are way better suited for what you are doing here.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll definitely take a look.  I think my biggest concern with step functions is cost, depending on how this workflow is able to be re-architect-ed.

Comment: It is always good to keep cost in mind. In my experience Lambdas are cheap enough to not make a dent in most scenarios compared to other resources you typically use. If cost is really a concern you could for example not run one Lambda per URL, but batch them etc. Furthermore, have a look at runtimes that are fast and don't use a lot of memory. AFAIK Go is your best option there. Dotnetcore is also pretty fast, but uses a lot more memory. (Remember you pay by duration * provisioned memory).

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned by JustinTArthur on [Github](https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/619#issuecomment-461859685):

> This warning is fine. If you dig into the urllib3 connection pool
> code, it's basically the pool of persistent connections and not the
> maximum number of concurrent connections you can have. The connections
> in the pool are re-used if they haven't been closed by the endpoint.
>
> If you'd like to boost the size of this pool, it can be done
> per-endpoint using the low-level botocore config. boto3 example:

```
import boto3
import botocore

client_config = botocore.config.Config(
    max_pool_connections=25,
)
boto3.client('lambda', config=client_config)
```

or

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', config=botocore.client.Config(max_pool_connections=50))
```

Answer (score 4):

So the [warning](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/1.25-series/src/urllib3/connectionpool.py#L303) itself comes from the `urllib3` library that `boto3` is using to make the HTTP requests.

The `max_pool_connections` config option sets `maxsize` for the [ConnectionPool](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#customizing-pool-behavior) class.

You can try to increase this option further to see if this will help but don't add more thread workers.

It's not clear how you create the client from your code snipped but it looks like resources are not threads safe and a separate one should be created for each thread / process:

[Multithreading and multiprocessing:](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html#multithreading-and-multiprocessing)

> **Note**
>
> Resources are **not** thread safe. These special classes contain
> additional meta data that cannot be shared between threads. When using
> a Resource, it is recommended to instantiate a new Resource for each
> thread, as is shown in the example above.
>
> Low-level clients **are** thread safe. When using a low-level client, it
> is recommended to instantiate your client then pass that client object
> to each of your threads.